# How to pass JSON all array values as a parameter to URI endpoint by looping?

Tags: arrays, json, postman, uri

I am trying to capture the JSON response value and passing it as Env var. For this I am looping the values captured from JSON. My problem is I am not able to pass the values from array index to the URI parameters and only the last index value is passed as a URI parameter.

How I should pass every index value?

Comment: You mean like that ```var uri = uri + "&param=" + value``` and then ```var response = http.request(uri);```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your example code. that'll be helpful.

You can loop through Json and create your string URL parameter query.

Comment: pm.sendRequest({
    url:"https:://***,
       method: 'GET',
    header: {
         'content-type': 'application/json',   
         'Authorization': pm.environment.get("access_token")
    },
}, 
    function (err, resp) {
    var len=resp.json().length;
     console.log("Total count" +len);
    for (var i = 0;i<resp.json().length;i++)
{
    pm.environment.set("attid", resp.json()[i].attendeeId);

     console.log("attendeeId value : " + pm.environment.get("attid"));
}
     
});